# How to import jsoncpp in cLion?

Tags: c++, clion

I am new to C++ and cLion and I'm using [JsonCpp](https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp) to parse object to text and vice-versa. I am a mac user and I have my .h jsoncpp files stored in /usr/include/jsoncpp and .dylib stored in /usr/lib.

What is the a way to include jsoncpp library into my project? I've tried:

```
include_directories(/usr/include/jsoncpp)
```

I can `#include <json.h>` but there is another error as shown below:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
"Json::Value::Value(Json::ValueType)", referenced from:
      Account::toJson() in Account.cpp.o
      StorageLoad::readfile(std::__1::basic_ifstream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) in StorageLoad.cpp.o
  "Json::Value::Value(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&)", referenced from:
      Account::toJson() in Account.cpp.o
```

How to resolve this error? I've spent many hours trying but no avail.

Comment: You will need to link the library, `target_link_libraries(your_executable jsoncpp)`, (if that is the name of the .dylib)

Comment: Do I need to specify the location of jsoncpp.dylib when I link the library? Since mine is in /usr/lib. Sorry I am still new :) Or the lib should be in my project instead?

Comment: `usr/lib` should be a default path the compiler/linker checks, but if not, add it with the [link_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/command/link_directories.html) command.

Comment: ok it works now thank you :) @melak47

Comment: It's working by accident because jsoncpp is installed to a default system-wide location on your system.  You should be using a cmake find package module (such as [described here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18005880/how-to-writing-a-cmake-module-for-jsoncpp)) to locate jsoncpp and then add the appropriate include and link settings.

Answer (score 0):

**This solution work on CLion 2021.1.3** (Mac Big Sur 11.6)

*The solution provided is based on this* [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40276737/how-to-add-allegro-library-in-clion-and-cmake), *which discusses a similar problem but with a different library.*

Install the library with [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/) using the Terminal and the command: 
 `brew install jsoncpp`

Then, **you need the installation location**. Either through the output of the installation or using the command: 
 `brew info jsoncpp` 
 
 The path should be listed and look like this:
**/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1**

Then, add the following to your CMakeLists.txt situated in your CLion project (don't forget to use the path you obtained instead).

```
INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/include )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib )

file(GLOB LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/jsoncpp/1.9.4_1/lib/*.dylib")
message("LIBRARIES = ${LIBRARIES}")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(myProjectName ${LIBRARIES})
```

Reload your CMake (if not done automatically).

Then you are free to use the JSON library you need in your project files using the syntax:

```
#include <json/ ... >
```

Example:

```
#include <json/json.h>
#include <json/value.h>
#include <json/writer.h>
#include <json/reader.h>
...
```