# How to add allegro Library in Clion and CMake?

Tags: c++, macos, cmake, clion, allegro

I am trying to compile my game project using Clion IDE but I have a problem when porting allegro 5. I get this error:

```
main.cpp:2:10: fatal error: 'allegro/allegro.h' file not found
   #include <allegro/allegro.h>
```

My CMakeLists is:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(testAllegro)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testAllegro ${SOURCE_FILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/include )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/lib )

file(GLOB LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/allegro/5.2.1.1_1/lib/*.dylib")
message("LIBRARIES = ${LIBRARIES}")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testAllegro  ${LIBRARIES})
```

Just I want to ask how can I add external Library allegro to Clion?

Comment: Where is located your file `allegro/allegro.h`? I guess it is not in `/usr/local/include`. Do you have any package installed for allegro? A file called `findallegro.cmake`, `allegroConfig.cmake`, or `allegro-config.cmake`?

Comment: As libraries are searched under `/usr/local/Cellar/allegro/`, header files are located there too. So, you have to issue `include_directories` command with appropriate path.

Comment: Hi @Tsyvarev  I used homebrew to install allegro [link](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Installing_with_homebrew) and it is say " Allegro should be installed into /usr/local/lib and /usr/local/include."

Comment: If so, why do you use libraries under `/usr/local/Cellar/allegro/` for link with?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

when you install allegro using homebrew [link](https://wiki.allegro.cc/index.php?title=Installing_with_homebrew)

use this cmake to compile clion project

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(testAllegro)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")

set(SOURCE_FILES main.cpp)
add_executable(testAllegro ${SOURCE_FILES})

INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/Cellar/allegro/5.2.1.1_1/include )
LINK_DIRECTORIES(  /usr/local/Cellar/allegro/5.2.1.1_1/lib )

file(GLOB LIBRARIES "/usr/local/Cellar/allegro/5.2.1.1_1/lib/*.dylib")
message("LIBRARIES = ${LIBRARIES}")

TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(testAllegro  ${LIBRARIES})
```

Comment: it's works to me, i just change to newer version of cmake.